# Can Harvest's Chosen work with the Python Pyramid Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, pyramid, jquery-chosen

And if yes, how do I set it up to do so? Otherwise, any alternatives?
I'm running this in Amazon's aws service, so I've got a linux server running Fedora.

I need npm to install chosen, but since I'm already running the python framework is it okay to install node.js on top of that?

Answer (score 2):

[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) is a JQuery/Prototype plugin which turns plain boring selects into nice fancy selects, right?

It absolutely totally can work with Pyramid. and you don't even need node.js for that, unless you want to modify the plugin itself (which is written in CoffeeScript) - there are compiled JavaScript versions provided in their repository, for example this is the [minified version which works with jQuery](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/blob/master/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js) - just put it where your other static files are and include it in your template with the `script` tag

In case you still want to install node.js you can do that too, it won't interfere with Pyramid.